# Can a US registered motorglider be flown in Canadian airspace when piloted by a pilot with the appropriate FAA glider license?

Tags: icao, transport-canada

Is a PPL-Glider recognized as ICAO approved? Can a US registered motorglider be flown in Canadian airspace (or land at an appropriate Canadian airport) when piloted by a pilot with the appropriate FAA glider license? (NOT an add on to a PPL SEL)

Answer (score 2):

Unless your license says on its face that it doesn't meet ICAO requirements (as FAA student, sport and recreational licenses do), then when you are flying an aircraft registered in that same ICAO member state, that state's licensing rules apply and all other states must accept it as valid regardless of their own rules.

So, in your example, if the FAA says your aircraft is a "glider" and you have a private glider license, then you're legal in Canada even if, for instance, Transport Canada thinks your aircraft is an "airplane" and would require an airplane license for their own pilots to fly it.

Comment: Also if it has a radio, you would need a radio station license, this isn't required in the US, but it is in Canada, even if flying an N registered aircraft.

Comment: @RonBeyer Agreed, but I assume there's plenty of other Q/A on that issue, so I felt it best to limit the response to what was actually asked.

Comment: Good to go without a medical?

Comment: @pericynthion I'm not 100% sure on that. New question?